# Group items by SUM of quantities and MIN date

Tags: sql, group-by, sum, min

I've got a table like this:

[image]

My intent is to create a table which shows, for each Order num and Item:

- The Total quantity ordered
- The minimum Expected delivery date
- The minimum Confirmed Delivery Date

Like this:

[image]

I tried to use

```
SELECT 'Order num.',
       Item,
       SUM(table.Qty) AS 'Total qty',
       Supplier,
       SUM(table.Qty) * UnitValue AS 'Total price',
       MIN(ExpectedDeliveryDate),
       MIN(ConfirmedDeliveryDate)
  FROM table
 GROUP BY 'Order num.', Item, Supplier, 
           MIN(ExpectedDeliveryDate), MIN(ConfirmedDeliveryDate)
 ORDER BY 'Order num.', Item
```

But it doesn't work. Can you help me? Many thanks.

Comment: Ciao! You can start with unquoting `'Order num.'` which is just a literal, but not returning the value of a column currently. Then remove expressions with aggregations(`MIN(...), MIN(...)`) next to GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

A question: Do you really have a column `Order num` with as space in it? I do not think this is possible, at least I never used such a name for a database column name.
I made a query that assumes the column is named "Ordernum". Likewise for the `Order date`.

In general, in the SELECT clause you have to use aggregate functions (MIN, MAX, ...) for all those columns that are not part of the "GROUP BY". That means for all columns except `Ordernum` and `Item`

I am not sure about the desired "Total price" column, but this should more or less produce the result:

```
SELECT Ordernum AS 'Order num.',
       MAX(Orderdate) AS 'Order date.',
       Item,
       SUM(Qty) AS 'Total qty',
       MAX(UnitValue) AS 'Unit price', -- "MAX" only need for the syntax here, no real aggregate
       Max(Supplier),                  -- "MAX" only need for the syntax here, no real aggregate
       MIN(ExpectedDeliveryDate),
       MIN(ConfirmedDeliveryDate)
  FROM table
 GROUP BY Ordernum, Item 
 ORDER BY Ordernum, Item
```